# ASP page to run under service account

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7

I have an asp page, done in VB, that Im using to prep PCs before I install an OS onto them.
I have the page all coded and I have a service account created with all the necessary access.

I have an application pool configured in IIS to run under the service account with the page added as an application.

However, when a user runs the page - it runs the code with their access and credentials - I want it to run with the service accounts permissions.

Is this possible ? I thought having the application pool configured would be enough to do this?

The page is using windows authentication to to grant access to the page also.

~~some code from the default page:

```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="asp._Default"  %>
   .....
   .....

   asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="405px" Width="693px" >                  
   </asp:ListBox>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="GO!" Width="168px" />
```

GO!
Will then run the VB behind the page:

```
 if pcname <> Nothing AndAlso user <> Nothing AndAlso MAC <> Nothing AndAlso asset_tag <> Nothing Then
            writelog("Starting Prep - |MachineName:" & pcname & " |Username:" & user & " |MAC:" & MAC & " |Asset_tag:" & asset_tag & " |Prepper:" & (Page.User.Identity.Name), "Main", "1")
            writelog("Starting AD prep for: " & pcname, "Factory", "1")
            do_AD_prep(pcname, user, asset_tag)
            writelog("Starting SCCM prep for: " & pcname, "Factory", "1")
            do_SCCM_Prep(pcname, MAC, user)
            writelog("Starting ePO prep for: " & pcname, "Factory", "1")
            do_EPO_prep(pcname, user)**
```

~~Site Master:

```
 <%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" Inherits="asp.SiteMaster" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head runat="server">
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">        
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" /> 
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
    </head>
    <body>
     <form runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
     <Scripts>
         <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272931&clcid=0x409 --%>
        <%--Framework scripts--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site scripts--%>
```

Comment: can you include a code sample? BTW: If it's client side javascript, then it will run under the user's account.

Comment: any particular bit you want to see?

Comment: the top of the code block with the declarations

Comment: the code in the code behind (default.aspx.vb) should be running under the app pool account. Double check in IIS that your app has the app pool set to the app pool that you created.

Comment: hmm, I'm almost 100% sure it is, but ill check again

Comment: yep - confirmed the application pool is running under the service account